# Importing Java class from Xtext dsl

Tags: java, dsl, xtext

I am new to Xtext. I use a model class in my dsl like that:

```
Model abc:
 variable1
 variable2
```

and import class like that:

```
import a.b.c
```

What I want to do is, when I say import a.b.c (which is a java class in same directory). Editor must recognise this a.b.c class and refer it as a model like:

modelname = classname

variable names = variables in the class.

I wrote a different class too, which gets the references of variables in model class. So, if I say variable1 in that class and if there is no variable named variable1 in all models there will be a syntax error. It works when I write a model class in dsl, however I could not do it with using my import class.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sry I cannot follow you. Can you give more context. EG a grammar and a complete Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here may be a starting point

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.Xbase

generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"

import "http://www.eclipse.org/xtext/common/JavaVMTypes" as types

Model:
    imports=XImportSection?
    elements+=Element*
    ;

Element:
    "element" "{"
        "modelname" "=" type=JvmTypeReference
        "variable" "names" "=" memberReferences+=MemberReference ("," memberReferences+=MemberReference)*
    "}"
;

MemberReference:
    member=[types::JvmField|ID]
;
```

and following adaption of the scope provider

```
package org.xtext.example.mydsl.scoping

import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EReference
import org.eclipse.xtext.EcoreUtil2
import org.xtext.example.mydsl.myDsl.Element
import org.xtext.example.mydsl.myDsl.MyDslPackage
import org.eclipse.xtext.scoping.IScope
import org.eclipse.xtext.scoping.Scopes
import org.eclipse.xtext.common.types.JvmDeclaredType
import org.eclipse.xtext.naming.QualifiedName

class MyDslScopeProvider extends AbstractMyDslScopeProvider {

    override getScope(EObject context, EReference reference) {
        if (reference == MyDslPackage.Literals.MEMBER_REFERENCE__MEMBER) {
            val element = EcoreUtil2.getContainerOfType(context, Element)
            if (element != null)  {
                val type = element.type.type
                if (type instanceof JvmDeclaredType) {
                    return Scopes.scopeFor(type.declaredFields, [QualifiedName.create(simpleName)], IScope.NULLSCOPE)
                }
            }
            return IScope.NULLSCOPE
        }
        super.getScope(context, reference)
    }

}
```

proposal provider

```
class MyDslProposalProvider extends AbstractMyDslProposalProvider {

    override protected isKeywordWorthyToPropose(Keyword keyword) {
        true
    }

}
```